# Convert library from using bitbanging to hardware SPI

Tags: library, spi, prototype, pcb-design

I'm using a MCP3008 8ch 10bit ADC to expand the Analog Inputs for the project I'm working on. The only library I can find for it is [here](https://github.com/nodesign/MCP3008) the library is ported from Adafruit's Raspberry Pi library [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/script). From what I can tell the library uses bitbanging as opposed to hardware SPI in order to communicate. I would like to use hardware SPI, but don't have the skills to write a library to communicate with it myself. Are there any resources for how to write a library like that, or anything I can read about on how to convert a library from bitbanging to hardware SPI?

Comment: What Arduino is this for?

Comment: It's for a PCB I designed based on the Atmega 1284 with hardware support added to the IDE with MightyCore found here: https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore

Comment: Typically, the library has a "sendByte" function in which it sends through "software spi" you would only have to re-write that.

Comment: The library uses some weird form of SPI. As it sends only 5 bits, and then reads 12 bits. SPI is normally a multiple of 8 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my google-fu needs work. I found [this](https://rheingoldheavy.com/mcp3008-tutorial-02-sampling-dc-voltage/) that works great using hardware SPI! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The standard AVR library has SPI handling. See, for example: http://www.gammon.com.au/spi

You don't have to write a library if you don't want, just communicate directly using SPI.

The datasheet for the MCP3008 has some tips for using an 8-bit SPI system to communicate with the device. In particular this chart:

[image: MCP3008 timings]

You can see from that, that you will need 3 x SPI.transfer. I don't have one here to test with, but the code would look like this:

```
digitalWrite (SS, LOW);  // select device
int result;
SPI.transfer (0x01);  // start bit
result = SPI.transfer (0b10000000);  // single, ch0
result = (result & 0b11) << 8;  // move to high-order byte
result |= SPI.transfer (0);   // lower order byte
digitalWrite (SS, HIGH);  // deselect
```

Untested, but this should be roughly it.